# How to add user defined variable leading zeros in C sprintf?

Tags: c++, integer, printf

I am working on a program in which I need to add leading zero for 3 numbers

So the code looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Check Examples


//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

int main()
{
    
    long int num =5;
    
    char CNum[10];
    
    sprintf(CNum,"%03ld",num) ;
    
    std::cout << CNum;
    
    return 0;
}

// Outputs 005
```

Now let's define the number of leading zeros in an integer variable named

`int blank = 3`

After that the code should look like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Check Examples


//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

int main()
{
    int blank = 3;
    long int num =5;
    
    char CNum[10];
    
    sprintf(CNum,"%03ld",num) ;
    
    std::cout << CNum;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then I edited the sprintf arguments like this

`sprintf(CNum,"%0%dld",blank,num);`

And this outputs

`%dld`

Instead of

`005`

Now, my main questions are,

1. Can I add user variable defined leading zeroes like this in sprintf?

   2. If Yes, how can I make my code do this?
   3. If No, is there any other way to perform the same action to get desired output?

Thank you, looking forward to your kind replies...

Comment: @S.M. This code seems to be easier than the code written by Paul below, but alas , I can't tick your answer here :)

Comment: If `num = -5`, what output expected? `"-005"`, `"-05"` or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the width dynamic (not hard-coded in the format string), you write it like this:

```
sprintf(CNum,"%0*ld",blank,num);
```

Instead of a hard-coded width `3` as in `"%03ld"`, the [asterisk indicates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) that the next argument (which must be of type `int`) is to be taken as the width.

Comment: Well, I guess I am seeing the asterisk sign being used like this for the first time , pardon me ,would you mind if I ask what the asterisk is there for?

Comment: I extended the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and flexible way of doing this would be to construct your own format string at runtime, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    long int num = 5;
    int n_zeroes = 3;
    
    std::string fmt = "%0" + std::to_string (n_zeroes) + "ld";
    
    char CNum [10];
    sprintf (CNum, fmt.c_str (), num) ;
    
    std::cout << CNum;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Aha82BIRAnfwzZjm)

Comment: Your one is a nice answer too

Answer (score 1):

> 3. If No, is there any other way to perform the same action to get desired output?

If you are outputting the result to `cout` anyway, you could do the formatting directly there:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(blank) << num;
```

Answer (score 1):

If one wants an output of at least 3 characters, padding with `'0'` as needed [@j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70409670/2410359):

```
sprintf(CNum,"%0*ld", blank, num);
```

If one wants an output of at least 3 *digits*, padding with `'0'` as needed:

```
sprintf(CNum,"%0.*ld", blank, num);
```

Outputs differs when `num < 0`.

---

Using `sprintf()` is prone to buffer overflow.

Could use `snprintf()` or more along the C++ lines of [@BoP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70410167/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the following code - it will solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
// Check Examples

//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

int main()
{
    int blank = 3;
    long int num =5;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    char blankZeros[16];
    char numStr[16];
    char CNum[16];

    sprintf(numStr,"%ld",num);
    for (i = 0; i < blank - strlen(numStr); i++)
        blankZeros[i] = '0';        // adding a zero
    blankZeros[i++] = '\0';         // end of string sign

    sprintf(CNum,"%s%s",blankZeros, numStr) ;

    std::cout << CNum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is good too but, It's quite complex and what that matters most is that your code is very big.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although I disagree about the complex. the code from @Paul Sanders e.g. is not efficient as I did, since it is using string catenation which is much more slow compare to mine. Also the sprintf() is a taken from C library and not C++

Comment: Rather than `strlen(numStr)`, code could use the return value from `sprintf()`: `int len = sprintf(numStr,"%ld",num);`.

Comment: When `num < 0`, this approach, code puts the zeros before the `"-"`.  If `num > 999`, `blankZeros[i] = '0';` overruns the buffer.

Comment: thanks @"chux - Reinstate Monica" regarding 1st comment. Regarding 2nd, indeed need to check for boundaries.